# How to build apache HCatalog 0.5.0?

Tags: apache, build, hadoop, hive, hcatalog

Its been almost 3 hours and I'm not able to build this. Please can anybody provide the steps. All the documents suggest to use hcatalog-src-0.5.0-incuvating.tar.gz but this is not available anywhere on internet (ad far as I've searched). Then I downloaded the branch 0.5.0 but as per the documentation
    http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.0/ds_HCatalog/install.pdf

of version 0.5.0 you have to build l=using command

```
ant_home/bin/ant -Dhcatalog.version=0.5.0 -Dforrest.home=forrest_home tar
```

Now the problem is that the build.xml do not have a target named 'tar'. So I just browsed the build.xml and tried the same command using target as 'package'

```
ant_home/bin/ant -Dhcatalog.version=0.5.0 -Dforrest.home=forrest_home package
```

but then its showing me error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\admnilesh\Desktop\hcatalog-branch-0.5\build.xml:71: The following error
 occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\nilesh\Desktop\hcatalog-branch-0.5\build-support\ant\deploy.xml:67:
Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read
 the metadata file for artifact 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar': Cannot find pa
rent: net.java:jvnet-parent for project: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9.1
 for project com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9.1
  com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  glassfish-repository (http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish),
  datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2)

Path to dependency:
        1) org.apache.hcatalog:webhcat:jar:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

We've been having the same trouble and discussing it over at the hcatalog-user mailing list for the last couple of days. You can have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HCATALOG-601 to see what's being done about this problem.

Quick summary though : Jersey 1.9 depended on a glassfish maven repo, which no longer exists. Bump your jersey dep version from 1.9 to 1.14 and you should be able to build.

Edit : One more thing - we're still going through the release process to release the 0.5.0 incubating candidate, the latest candidates are being put up currently on http://people.apache.org/~travis/ . We should see a public release in a couple of days. In the meanwhile, I suggest poking over at our hcatalog-user mailing list : http://incubator.apache.org/hcatalog/mailing_lists.html

Comment: I've downloaded the version 0.5 but this problem is still there... may I know where any how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while giving target "tar". On specifying the target as "package", the build proceeds ahead but fails with following error:

```
satish@dev1$ /usr/bin/ant -Dhcatalog.version=0.5.0 -Dforrest.home=/home/satish/work/forrest/apache-forrest-0.9 package

[artifact:dependencies] Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
[artifact:dependencies] ----------
[artifact:dependencies] 1) org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0
[artifact:dependencies] 

[artifact:dependencies] 
[artifact:dependencies]   Path to dependency: 
[artifact:dependencies]     1) org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-pig-adapter:jar:0.5.0-    incubating
[artifact:dependencies]     2) org.apache.hcatalog:hcatalog-core:jar:0.5.0
[artifact:dependencies] ----------
```

This issue got resolved by specifying project.version as "0.5.0-incubating" instead of "0.5.0" in build command line. The reason for error is that build installs hcatalog-core artifact as hcatalog-core-0.5.0-incubating.jar. However because of wrong project.version, the dependent projects were instead searching for hcatalog-core-0.5.0.jar.

Build succeeded with:

```
satish@dev1$ /usr/bin/ant -Dhcatalog.version=0.5.0-incubating -Dforrest.home=/home/satish/work/forrest/apache-forrest-0.9 package
```